# Create new array with another structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, structure

I want to create a new array based on an original array but with merged data.

Every **name** key need to have merged date+time (format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) with merged **scores**. All unique datetimes need to be available as key for each **name**.

**ARRAY ORIGINAL:**

```
"data": [{
        "name": "A",
        "history": [{
                "created": "2017-05-16 00:00:00",
                "score": "1"
            },
            {
                "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:10",
                "score": "1"
            },
            {
                "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:30",
                "score": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "history": [{
            "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:00",
            "score": "1"
        }]
    }
]
```

**ARRAY THAT I WANT:**

```
{ 
  [A]: { 
    "2017-05-16 00:00": 1, 
    "2017-05-16 00:01": 2 
  },  
  [B]: { 
    "2017-05-16 00:00": 0, 
    "2017-05-16 00:01": 1 
  } 
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out. I can't even think of an efficiënt way to do this, unfortunately. I tried to solve this issue with 5 `foreach` statements with no luck :(

Comment: You can't specify your own keys in JS arrays, you can only use `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. They aren't PHP arrays. You have to use objects to get key=>value pairs. Plus, you say you want an array, but you surround it in `{}` which is for objects.

Comment: do you need the brackets around the keys, like `[A]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two arrays for names and times as closure and generate for all names and times a property with zero value.

```js
var data = { data: [{ name: "A", history: [{ created: "2017-05-16 00:00:00", score: "1" }, { created: "2017-05-16 00:01:10", score: "1" }, { created: "2017-05-16 00:01:30", score: "1" }] }, { name: "B", history: [{ created: "2017-05-16 00:01:00", score: "1" }] }] },
    result = data.data.reduce(function (names, times) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!r[a.name]) {
                r[a.name] = {};
                times.forEach(function (time) {
                    r[a.name][time] = 0;
                });
                names.push(a.name);
            }
            a.history.forEach(function (o) {
                var time = o.created.slice(0, 16);
                if (times.indexOf(time) === -1) {
                    names.forEach(function (name) {
                        r[name][time] = 0;
                    });
                    times.push(time);
                }
                r[a.name][time] += +o.score;
            });
            return r;
        };
    }([], []), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, you are awesome!

Comment: there must be an easier way than this... - these are wow: `}([], []), {});`

Comment: @mplungjan, do you have an easier way?

Comment: I was wrecking my brain. Something like looping over history/created instead

Comment: @mplungjan, it's a problem with the two dimenstions of name and time, where all other result sets have to be initialized with zero if one of the two arrays is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object not an array, As arrays cannot have a key-value pair in javascript. There is no associative array concept in javascript. You have to use objects in javascript for that.

Here is how you can do what you are trying to achieve using objects.

```
value = {
   "data": [{
       "name": "A",
       "history": [{
       "created": "2017-05-16 00:00:00",
       "score": "1"
     },
     {
       "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:10",
       "score": "1"
     },
     {
       "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:30",
       "score": "1"
     }
   ]},
   {
     "name": "B",
     "history": [{
       "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:00",
       "score": "1"
     }]
   }]
  };

var result ={};
value.data.forEach(function(v){
  var score = {};
  for(var i=0;i<v.history.length;i++){
   score[v.history[i].created] = v.history[i].score;
  }
  result[v.name] = score;
});

console.log(result);
```

**Now you can access data as `result.A or result[A]` and `result.B or result[B]`**

**SNIPPET**

```js
value = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "A",
      "history": [{
          "created": "2017-05-16 00:00:00",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:10",
          "score": "1"
        },
        {
          "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:30",
          "score": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "history": [{
        "created": "2017-05-16 00:01:00",
        "score": "1"
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var result = {};
value.data.forEach(function(v) {
  var score = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < v.history.length; i++) {
    score[v.history[i].created] = v.history[i].score;
  }
  result[v.name] = score;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the solution. Nina Scholz gave me the right solution. Thank you for your time.